# Why does XCode 4 always copies all resource files on my iPhone after building?

Tags: xcode, resources, copy

I know there are alot of questions like "how to force XCode to always update resources" ect. But i have the opposite problem - XCode copying all my resources each time i hit 'Run', no matter what, and it takes too much time. Why XCode does not check for resources modification?
The whole project and resources are on a mounted network volume.

EDIT: Ok, i think i've got the point. There are two stages: "copy files to product" and "copy product to device". It looks like XCode copies and replaces the whole application bundle on the device each 'Run', and there is no way to force XCode to modify the bundle that is already present on executing device.

Comment: This is a pure speculation on my part, but you may want to make sure that your local system that runs Xcode and the server that owns the mounted volume have identical settings for the time (i.e. the current time, the time zone, daylight saving time settings, etc.) If your resource files appear to be modified in the future from the local system's standpoint, you will see the resources copied.

Comment: The time zone was actually different, but synchronization didn't helped me much.

Comment: You may want to double-check the "last modified" timestamps on the resource files (right-click them in the finder, and choose "Get Info"; look at the modified date at the top of the "info" dialog, and compare the dates on the local and the remote computers).

Comment: I have copied resources on local disk to test if it is network volume dependent. And the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

The work flow is as follows: 
Make the Product file (App!)
Fill the Product file with resources(Complete App!)
Download the Product file to local device(Done!)